# & and &&: Align three rows of display math material

Tags: equations, alignment, alignat

I'm aligning two equations using `&`. The first equation is very long. This is why I split it into two parts. How can I remove the space that is inserted between the first and the second term of the first equation? I assume that I am not doing this right.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{3}
    &\partial_{t_{s}}q_{s}+\nabla_{s}\cdot(\Vec{v}_{0,s}q_{s})&&+\partial_{x_{s}}\partial_{y_{s}}\overline{v_{0,m}v_{0,m}}-\partial_{x,s}\partial_{y,s}\overline{u_{0,m}u_{0,m}}+\partial_{x,s}\partial_{x,s}\overline{u_{0,m}v_{0,m}}\\&&&=\mathbf{k}\cdot\nabla_{s}\times\,Q_{\mathbf{v},2,s}+\frac{f_{0}}{\Bar{p}}\partial_{z}(\frac{p}{\partial_{z}\Bar{\Theta}}\Tilde{\Theta_{0}})\\
    &\partial_{t_{s}}\Tilde{\Theta}_{0}+\mathbf{v}_{0,s}\cdot\nabla_{s}\Tilde{\Theta}_{0}+\omega_{3,s}\partial_{z}\Bar{\Theta}=\overline{Q_{\Theta_{4}}}
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:**
The first equation should look like this:

[image]

Instead of this:

[image]

Comment: How exactly do you want the equations to be aligned? Could you provide an image?

Comment: @bonk See edit. The change in distance occurs when the second equation is added

Comment: if  using align you should not have & at the start, you are left aligning the first part so forcing the gap, but you have no alignment here use multline and remove all &

Comment: While it's ok to upvote good answers immediately, the site guidelines strongly suggest waiting a few hours at a minimum, and better even a day or two, before awarding an acceptance checkmark. That way, one doesn't inadvertently discourage others from posting additional, and potentially even better, answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use two separate alignment environments. Adding some vertical space between the two blocks helps in distinguishing the separate equations.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \begin{aligned}
  \partial_{t_{s}}q_{s}+\nabla_{s}\cdot(\vec{v}_{0,s}q_{s})
    & +\partial_{x_{s}}\partial_{y_{s}}\overline{v_{0,m}v_{0,m}}
      -\partial_{x,s}\partial_{y,s}\overline{u_{0,m}u_{0,m}}
      +\partial_{x,s}\partial_{x,s}\overline{u_{0,m}v_{0,m}}\\
    & =\mathbf{k}\cdot\nabla_{s}\times\,Q_{\mathbf{v},2,s}
      +\frac{f_{0}}{\bar{p}}\partial_{z}(\frac{p}{\partial_{z}\bar{\Theta}}\tilde{\Theta_{0}})
  \end{aligned}
\\[2ex]
& \partial_{t_{s}}\tilde{\Theta}_{0}
  +\mathbf{v}_{0,s}\cdot\nabla_{s}\tilde{\Theta}_{0}
  +\omega_{3,s}\partial_{z}\bar{\Theta}=\overline{Q_{\Theta_{4}}}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

There is no difference whatsoever between `\bar` and `\Bar`, `\tilde` and `\Tilde`, `\vec` and `\Vec`. I'd recommend using the lowercase versions.

[image]

Comment: Surely the tilde over the last Theta in the middle line shouldn't include the subscript.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Definitely! I didn't notice it, but your eagle's eye striked again!

Answer (score 3):

Getting rid of most of the `&`s fixes the alignment. I assume you wanted the equal signs to be aligned?

PS: I took the liberty of changing the parentheses in the second line to `\left( ... \right)` so that it matches the height of the fraction. Also, please use whitespace in your code; it's very hard to read otherwise.

Edit: Added more `&`s to align the first terms of each equation.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
    &\partial_{t_{s}} q_{s} + \nabla_{s} \cdot (\Vec{v}_{0, s} q_{s}) &&+ \partial_{x_{s}} \partial_{y_{s}} \overline{v_{0, m} v_{0, m}} - \partial_{x, s} \partial_{y, s} \overline{u_{0, m} u_{0, m}} + \partial_{x, s} \partial_{x, s} \overline{u_{0, m} v_{0, m}}\\
    &&&= \mathbf{k} \cdot \nabla_{s} \times \, Q_{\mathbf{v}, 2, s} + \frac{f_{0}}{\Bar{p}} \partial_{z} \left( \frac{p}{\partial_{z} \Bar{\Theta}} \Tilde{\Theta}_{0} \right)\\
    &\partial_{t_{s}} \Tilde{\Theta}_{0} + \mathbf{v}_{0, s} \cdot \nabla_{s} \Tilde{\Theta}_{0} + \omega_{3, s} \partial_{z} \Bar{\Theta} &&= \overline{Q_{\Theta_{4}}}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Aligned equations]

Comment: Very good. Do you use MAC to put an image?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is not entirely what I wanted. The first term of each equation should also be aligned.

Comment: Like this? The only relevant difference between my code and yours is that I aligned the equal sign in the second equation.

Comment: No. I want both equations to be left-aligned but I don't want the space between the first and the second term of the first equation. Maybe that's not possible?

Comment: Do you also want to keep the plus sign aligned with the equal signs? If so, then I don't think it's possible, because the first term of the second equation is much longer than the first term of the first equation.

Comment: Yes, that's what I would like to do. 
Is there maybe another way?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an answer with an overall structure that's similar to [@egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/706762/5001), with the following four differences: (a) nest an `aligned` environment inside an `align*` environment, (b) increase the size of the parentheses around the `\frac{p}{\partial_{z}\bar{\Theta}}\tilde{\Theta_{0}}` term, (c) change `\tilde{\Theta_{0}}` to `\tilde{\Theta}_{0}` in said term (for consistency with the appearance of the terms in line 3), and (d) use `\jot` to increase the vertical space betweens lines 2 and 3.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&\begin{aligned}
  \partial_{t_{s}}q_{s}+\nabla_{\!s}\cdot(\Vec{v}_{0,s}q_{s})
  &+\partial_{x_{s}}\partial_{y_{s}}\overline{v_{0,m}v_{0,m}}
   -\partial_{x,s}\partial_{y,s}\overline{u_{0,m}u_{0,m}}
   +\partial_{x,s}\partial_{x,s}\overline{u_{0,m}v_{0,m}}\\ % end of line 1
  &=\mathbf{k}\cdot\nabla_{\!s}\times Q_{\mathbf{v},2,s}
   +\frac{f_{0}}{\Bar{p}}\partial_{z}
   \Bigl(\frac{p}{\partial_{z}\Bar{\Theta}}\Tilde{\Theta}_{0}\Bigr) 
 \end{aligned} \\[\jot] % end of line 2
&\partial_{t_{s}}\Tilde{\Theta}_{0}
 +\mathbf{v}_{0,s}\cdot\nabla_{\!s}\Tilde{\Theta}_{0}
 +\omega_{3,s}\partial_{z}\Bar{\Theta}
 =\overline{Q_{\Theta_{4}}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```